# Binding pry not being called in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry, pry-rails

I'm currently writing specs for my Rails controller. I can't seem to get any puts statement or binding.pry, or binding.remote_pry working.

I am able to get the remote pry working in the development environment.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'daemons'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-remote'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you need to `require 'pry'` somewhere in your test environment before invoking it.  Your `spec_helper.rb`, `test_helper.rb` or similar is probably a good place.

Comment: It works (adding it to test_helper.rb). This answer should be marked as good.

Answer (score 0):

All credit to [@Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30640509/5783745), here's where I placed `require 'pry'` (note that the first 9 lines are what comes with a fresh install of rspec):

```rb
# specs/rails_helper.rb
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!
 
require 'pry' # <----- HERE
```